# msql query to push notification

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on online Notification API, in my application i want to send a notification dynamically on the start date and stop it at the end date. so here goes my logic

```
$mydate=getdate(date("U"));
$date = "$mydate[mon]/$mydate[mday]/$mydate[year]";
$sql= "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE start_date='".$date."' ORDER BY notification time  LIMIT 1";
```

so now it sends me a notification when my todays date matches my start date.
but i want to end the notification at end date.
but it stops the notification when start date ends.

Please guide with the logic on how to shot notification on the start date and stop it on end date.

Comment: start_date is not in a mysql date type

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your question right, but I would something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `start_date`<='$date' AND `end_date`>'$date' LIMIT 1;
```

Be careful to add the proper indexes on *start_date* and *end_date*. You might also want to flush your table regularly with something like:

```
DELETE FROM `Table` WHERE `done` = 1 limit 100;
```

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question , I want show only 1 notification which starts at the date given and should end at the given date . So using my mysqli query I am able to target the right notification from database but it shoots notification only for a day and not until the end date.so I want a logic where I can shoot a notification if the start date of notification is equal to today's date and stop shooting it when end date is equal to end date.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your query you have to pick all the notifications between start time and end time.

At this time, you are taking notification of only start date, and you have limited it to 1 also.